# telegram ,whatsapp, viber tcp connection

Tags: android, networking, tcp, xmppframework, whatsapp

I was analyzing chat application like telegram or whatsapp. as you know they are using a tcp connection to server.
the big problem of tcp connection is that when there is any issue in internet connection the xmpp client will be disconnected from server without telling server that i am disconnected and tcp connection will be open from server and message will be lost.

So one way for client and server to understand connection is lost is using ping .that is we set a time for server and client to ping each other and if connection is lost retry to connect. and again main problem of this solution is that it drains a lot of battery charge if for example we set client to ping each 10 second and if we set server to ping user each 40 second it will put a lot of load on server when we are dealing with lots of user.

But telegram and whatsapp doesn't have this problem because they will understand the tcp connection is lost up to 30 second and telegram is even faster and it will know in 4 or 5 second.

My problem is that i dont think whatsapp or telegram are using ping system actually pinging server each 10 second because it will drains battery.

What is your idea ? are they using ping system or they have found any solution for it.

I would be very thankful if anybody explain me how they are doing that

Comment: i am not developer but maybe this link has the answer.  https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/cd9d188fe2bed8e5df5a1b0f0bd34ab336c2892f/TMessagesProj/src/main/java/org/telegram/messenger/ConnectionsManager.java

Answer (score 3):

TCP itself has a way of detecting connection loss, so you don't need to ping at all. However, you can make a higher level heartbeat signal, in case the usual TCP way isn't fast enough.

http://www.roman10.net/android-tcp-client-and-server-communication-programmingillustrated-with-example/

Answer (score 1):

You need to have some keepalive mechanism and have your server detect connection loss by missed keepalive. Otherwise, depending on the server configuration it can take a very long time to detect connection loss at TCP level.

Comment: Really appreciate your answer

Comment: in wikipedia is said that usally it is set to 2 hours and if we set it to 10 second for example i think it will drain a lot of battery  and as i told i checked telegram i mean client itself and when it is on foreground it will understand TCP connection is lost up to 10 second . i couldnt check it when is in background that connection is running or not .what i know that when client goes to background presence api will be killed but i cant understand connection will be closed or just presence api will be killed. what is exact time that whatsapp or telegram has set foe keepalive?

Comment: in my testing before i have used wifi with vpn connection and when i connect to vpn android will be connected to internet. when app is in foreground i will disconnect vpn and server think it is online and i close app and it goes to background and it cant inform server that i am offline so i dont think server will send any push .and i send a message to it from another device and again i connect to internet via vpn but with another ip to be sure that tcp connection again wont be established.

Comment: so in this situation app dont think any change in connection is made because android just cant understand change in wifi or 3g but telegram will get message very fast (in 5 sec) and i dont think message is pushed because server all the time says user is online

Comment: Presence status can be made independent from the TCP/IP connection state. There is nothing that says it must be linked (and actually ejabberd SaaS is working like that: you can be seen online even if you are disconnected and can receive your messages through push).